# How are the two statements different?

Tags: c, compare, depth-first-search

In DFS traversal,when traversing `adjlist` to get the next non-visited vertex(marked by `'1'` in an array `int visit[100]`) and backtracking by popping next value from stack(=i).

The first one gives me the correct answer,the second one crashes the program.

*How are the 2 statements different?*

```
array=graph*   //psuedo code 
link=adjList*
head=adjListNode*

while(temp!=NULL)         //temp=array->link[i].head->next
    if(visit[temp->key]==1)  //checking if visited
            temp=temp->next;
        else
            break;

 while(visit[temp->key]==1 && temp!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;
```

Comment: Try this `while( temp!=NULL && visit[temp->key]==1)`. First check not `null` condition then check visited condition, it may work.

Comment: your welcome. I am keeping this as my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
while( temp!=NULL && visit[temp->key]==1)
```

First you need to check `temp!=NULL` then, if condition is true, you can check
`visit[temp->key]==1`

As condition used by you first checks `visit[temp->key]==1` without checking temp is NULL or not, which is causing crash.
It will work similar like your first condition in which you are check first `while(temp!=NULL)` condition then `if(visit[temp->key]==1)`.